# zf3 fieldset form bind date field error - Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion

Tags: php, zend-framework3

When I used fieldset form,other than date field data set during edit time.But during edit time,date data not set properly and gives error.

**when I bind blog object into form,gives error "Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion" because of date object.If I comment date related field form bind properly.**

Please provide solutions for how to set date data during edit time.

Blog Entity:

```
   /**
   *  @var \DateTime
   *
   *  @ORM\Column(name="start_date", type="date", nullable=false)
   */       
   protected $startDate;
```

Add Blog fieldset :

```
   $this->add([
        'name' => 'startDate',
        'type' => 'text',
        'attributes' => [
            'id' => 'startDate',
            'class' => 'form-control date',
        ],
        'options' => [
            'label' => 'Start date',
            'label_options' => [
                'disable_html_escape' => true,
            ],
        ]
    ]);
```

controller code :

```
    public function editAction() {
       try {
          $blogId = $this->params()->fromRoute('id');
          $form = new AddBlogForm($this->em, $blogId);
          $blogObj = $this->em->getRepository(Blog::class)
                          ->find($blogId);

          **$form->bind($blogObj);**    
          $request = $this->getRequest();
          if ($request->isPost()) {
             $requestData = $request->getPost()->toArray();
             $form->setData($requestData);
             if ($form->isValid()) {
                 $this->em->flush();
                 $this->em->commit();
                 $this->flashmessenger()->addSuccessMessage('Blog upate');
                 return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
             }
         }

         return [
             'form' => $form,
             'blogId'=> $this->params()->fromRoute('id')
         ];
       } catch (\Exception $ex) {
          $this->em->rollback();
          throw new \Exception($ex->getMessage());
       }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried answers from [14760946](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760946/zend-form-bootstrap-annotation-datepicker-object-provided-to-escape-helper-but)?

Comment: Thanks,above solutions also work.But it's not recommended because if form have more than 1 field than we have write below code for every field   

$form->get('datenais')->setValue($document->getDatenais()->format('Y-m-d'));


Instead of above, I got below solution by write in entity

/**
     * Get startDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getStartDate() {
        if($this->startDate != NULL) {
            return $this->startDate->format('m/d/Y');
        }
        
        return $this->startDate;
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zend form bootstrap annotation datepicker "Object provided to Escape helper, but flags do not allow recursion"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760946/zend-form-bootstrap-annotation-datepicker-object-provided-to-escape-helper-but)